# powershell read-host into range operator

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to find a way to have a variable that has a read-host where you can enter numbers in a range operator format.

I essentially want to do the following

```
$domain=Domain.Host    
$Servers = Read-Host "What servers do you want to check?" #this is where a user would input @(1..10)
$CompleteServer = $Servers$Domain
Get-Service -ComputerName $CompleteServer -Name "Service Name"
```

So  $CompleteServer would contain

01.domain.host

02.domain.host

...

10.domain.host

Is this at all possible, to atleast even have a read-input go into a range operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Invoke-Expression`, but be careful to validate the input:

```
$UserInput = 
Read-Host 'Enter a number range (eg. 1..5)'

If ($UserInput -match '^\d+\.\.\d+$')
  { $NumberRange = Invoke-Expression $UserInput }
  Else { Write-Host 'Input not in correct format.' }

$NumberRange

Enter a number range (eg. 1..5): 2..6
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: That is just about perfect. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

`Read-Host` only reads strings, I think.

If you want them to input a list, you can let them to separate input by commas or space.

For Example

```
$input = Read-Host 'enter input, separated by commas'
$inputList = $input -split ','
```

or

```
$input = Read-Host 'enter input, separated by space'
$inputList = $input -split ' '
```

if user needs to enter a long string you might want them to input with newlines or stuff:

```
$inputList = @()
Write-Host 'enter your input, when you finish one item, press enter, if you finish all the items, enter "END" and press enter'
$input = Read-Host 'enter the input'
while(input -nq 'END') {
     $inputs.Add(input)
     $input = Read-Host 'enter the input'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Yea i was afraid it would be something like that. However, i'm still not completely convinced that Read-host only accepts strings. Doing the following.

PS C:\user> [INT]$Int2 = Read-Host "Enter an int"
Write-host $int2

Enter an int: NotanInt

Cannot convert value "NotanInt" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: you can always cast string to int, but that doesn't mean the returned value of read-host is an int.

Comment: Here is a reference https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849945.aspx. if you see the output section, that is a string or a secure string.